# Permission denied accessing shell via VBA

Tags: vba

Very simple question, but I cannot figure this out. My code was working fine last week and then all of a sudden it no longer works (no updates on my end). Every call to Shell now hits a permissions error. I can recreate it simply with this:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "C:\Test.vbs"
```

Which when run gives me the error, even when admin privilages:

Run-time error '70':
Permission denied

All locations are tusted in the trust centre, macros turned on.

Im suspecting maybe a group user policy change? Others have suggested that UAC may be blocking it, but I have temporarily turned that off with no success.

Answer (score 1):

After thorough searching we have identified the issue, latest offical Microsoft Office security patches have  blocked our scripts from access the Windows Shell/cmd, exceptions had to be made within Windows Defender to allow them to function.